# File IO in PHP doens't work

Tags: php, file-io

For a school assignment I have to write a script in PHP. It has to create an array with names and write the array to a file. Then it has to delete the array, read the names in the file and the echo them.

This doesn't work:

```
<?php
    $names = array("Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3", "Name 4", "Name 5");
    $filename = "names.txt";
    $handle = fopen($filename, "wb+"); //open as read and write
    $string = implode("\r\n", $names); //name on each line
    fwrite($handle, $string); //write line

    $names = array(); //empty array
    print_r($names); //print empty array
    $string = fread($handle, filesize($filename)); //read file
    $names = explode("\r\n", $string); //lines to array
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        echo("<br>\n$name");
    }
    fclose($handle);
?>
```

But this works:

```
<?php
    $names = array("Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3", "Name 4", "Name 5");
    $filename = "names.txt";
    $handle = fopen($filename, "wb"); //open as write
    $string = implode("\r\n", $names); //name on each line
    fwrite($handle, $string); //write line
    fclose($handle); //close

    $handle = fopen($filename, "r"); //open as read
    $names = array(); //empty array
    print_r($names); //print empty array
    $string = fread($handle, filesize($filename)); //read file
    $names = explode("\r\n", $string); //lines to array
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        echo("<br>\n$name");
    }
    fclose($handle);
?>
```

I don't get why it works when I close and reopen the file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The second script is correct, not first.

Comment: It's much easier to work with `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` rather than using the whole fread/filesize/fclose ordeal.

Comment: @N.B. Thanks for the suggestion, but the chapter was about fopen, fwrite and so on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need is to restart the file pointer  because when using [`fwrite()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php):

> [`fwrite()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) writes the contents of string to the file stream pointed to by handle.
>
> - length bytes have been read
> - **EOF (end of file) is reached**
> - a packet becomes available or the socket timeout occurs (for network streams)
> - if the stream is read buffered and it does not represent a plain file, at most one read of up to a number of bytes equal to the chunk size (usually 8192) is made; depending on the previously buffered data, the size of the returned data may be larger than the chunk size.

if you look at [`fread()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)

> [`fread()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) reads up to length bytes **from the file pointer** referenced by handle. Reading stops as soon as one of the [these conditions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php#refsect1-function.fread-description) is met:

So at at the time you are calling `fread($handle, filesize($filename));` you are already at the **end of file** therefore nothing would be displayed.

To resolve this just use `fseek` to restart the pointer back to the beginning of the file

Example :

```
 fseek($handle, 0);
```

Yon't don't need to close the file .. your first code would work perfectly

**Edit**

You can also you [rewind](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php) from PHP DOC

> Sets the file position indicator for handle to the beginning of the file stream.

```
 rewind($handle);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I now understand better how reading and writing works.

Comment: Good to know i was able to help

Answer (score -2):

The second script is correct. The reason is that if you open a file for writing, you can not use to read, so you have to close the file and reopen it in read.

Comment: -1. false. w+ is [reading and writing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), but when the write is complete, the file pointer is at EOF and there's nothing to read.